# Can't dereference the mapped_type of a map const iterator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

Given the code in Visual Studio 2010:

```
void Foo::Bar() const
{
    map_t::const_iterator iter(my_map_.find(key));

    if(my_map_.end() != iter)
        DoStuff(iter->second);
}
```

Do stuff will take the mapped_type by value. The mapped type is a copyable, movable, assignable type.

I get error messages that the key/value pair can't be copied when trying to access second. Even if I write on their own lines:

```
iter->second;
(*iter).second;
```

to ensure it's nothing to do with DoStuff...

I presume the iterator is making a copy of the key/value pair before returning operator-> or operator*.

How do I get a copy of the mapped type?

EDIT:

The map itself is of unsigned shorts to boost variants, roughly as such:

```
typedef struct{} empty_t;
typedef boost::variant<empty_t, double, long, some POD types> variant_t;
typedef std::map<unsigned short, variant_t> map_t;
```

And then as a private member of the class:

```
map_t my_map_;
```

And to be clear, the problem is not in passing to DoStuff. I can remove that line, and simply dereference the iterator and access second, and that will cause the compiler error.

```
if(my_map_.end() != iter)
        iter->second; //Doesn't do anything, but illustrates the error.
```

Comment: Can you post code that exibits *only* that problem?

Comment: If `T = std::map<K, T>`, then `T::value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`. Mind the constness.

Comment: Correct, but I don't want K, I want V.

Comment: Are you certain that the `variant_t` type consists only of POD types?  I didn't repro this by cobbling together my own example based on your code snippets and filling in some blanks.  I think you may need to post a self-contained repro example as Luchian Grigore suggested.  Or at the very least copy/paste the relevant error messages, which should give much more detail than "the key/value pair can't be copied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

WAYYYYY away from this code, and a couple abstractions deep, the iterators to the map were being passed to std::partition! You can't partition a map, it seems.

I copied the contents of the map into a local vector and continued processing from there, and it cleared up all the error messages.

I have no idea why the compiler was getting so throughly confused. The problem code was somewhere completely unrelated. But it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Answer invalid given question update as a result of boost::variant (will update with final answer once the rest of the problem information is available).

If DoStuff takes it's variable by reference or by value and you're passing the variable directly from a const_iterator then DoStuff must have a const reference or const value overloaded function call (unless the object type has a default const to non-const conversion available). Otherwise the compiler complains because your treating a const element as a non-const.

Another option is to assign iter->second to another variable (via constructor or assignment depending on the element type) and pass that into DoStuff -- but it's better to define a const overload version of the function.

Comment: I mentioned it in my original post, but perhaps I wasn't clear. I can remove the DoStuff line entirely. If the body just contained the iterator declaration and "iter->second;", then that line there gives me the error message. So, assigning to a local mapped_type is irrelevant at that point. I'll edit the original post to add clarifications. DoStuff is pass by value, btw.

Comment: Ok, so you didn't mention you were using boost::variant before -- do you have the same error if you use a map of a single instance of the varient? Try using "typedef long variant_t;" and see if the error persists. If it goes away I think your problem is that the iterator can't dereference a variant type and you may need to do a wrapper on the iterator reference via a StaticVisitor class to handle various cases ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.static-visitor )